# Read an xlsx file and search for a specific value

Tags: javascript, node.js, xlsx

I need to search for a value inside an xlsx in column A and return the values ​​from the other columns [B-G]

I have a function that reads the xlsx:

**userData.js**

```
function personData (){

    let XLSX = require('xlsx')
    let workbook = XLSX.readFile(`${__dirname}/\person.xlsx`);
    let sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
    let xlData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]]);
    return xlData
}
module.exports = personData;
```

and return the data in the following way

```
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'Bob', //I need to search for this attribute and return all others
    full_name: 'Robert Shawn',
    number: 123456789,
    team: 'IT',
    profile: 'ALL',
    file: 5672,
    email: 'robsh@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Jean',
    full_name: 'Mary Jean',
    number: 987654321,
    team: 'HR',
    profile: 'Sales',
    file: 1285,
    email: 'mjean@gmail.com'
  }
]
```

now i need to search for a value within that result and return the other information
Something like:

**user.js**

```
const usersData = require ('./userData')
let valueToSearch = 'Bob' //search for that value inside the name attribute

let personData = usersData(valueToSearch)
console.log(personData); //return Bob's data
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created one custom `searchUsersData` function for search value from json and specific key, using `search` function.

```js
/**
 * @Info: This function will return searched object
 * @Arg1: data => your user json data
 * @Arg2: searchValue => value that you want to search
 * @Arg3: searchKey => key name that you want to search value inside this key
*/
function searchUsersData(data, searchValue, searchKey){
  let returnData = [];
  data.forEach((obj, objKey) => {
      if( obj[searchKey].toString().search(searchValue.toString()) >= 0 )
         returnData.push(obj);
  });
  return returnData;
}

const usersData = [{
    id: 0,
    name: 'Bob', //I need to search for this attribute and return all others
    full_name: 'Robert Shawn',
    number: 123456789,
    team: 'IT',
    profile: 'ALL',
    file: 5672,
    email: 'robsh@gmail.com'
  },{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Jean',
    full_name: 'Mary Jean',
    number: 987654321,
    team: 'HR',
    profile: 'Sales',
    file: 1285,
    email: 'mjean@gmail.com'
  },{
    id: 0,
    name: 'Test Bob', //I need to search for this attribute and return all others
    full_name: 'Robert Shawn',
    number: 123456789,
    team: 'IT',
    profile: 'ALL',
    file: 5672,
    email: 'robsh@gmail.com'
}];

let valueToSearch = 'Bob'; //search for that value inside the name attribute
// specify a key name that you want to search inside, i have passed 'name' key
// SEARCH NAME
let personData = searchUsersData(usersData, valueToSearch, 'name');
console.log('name search: ', personData); //return Bob's data

// SEARCH NUMBER
valueToSearch = 123456789;
personData = searchUsersData(usersData, valueToSearch, 'number');
console.log('number search: ', personData); //return Bob's data
```

I have added 3 object for testing purpose, Searching for `Bob` and this will return 2 objects, because 2 object have Bob word in name key.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys!
both worked the way I intended, I'm running some more tests

@turivishal
I tried to change the search field to look for other columns, for example:


```
let valueToSearch = '123456789' 
let personData = searchUsersData(usersData, valueToSearch, "number");
console.log(personData);
```

However I get this error message, I couldn't understand why it is working only with the parameter "name" 
do I need to adjust something else?

TypeError: obj[searchKey].search is not a function

Comment: Okay i have updated code and also added example, there was a type casting error, number kay has number value, and search will work in string value.

Answer (score 3):

Given the data already present in `userData`, you can use [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the object (`row`) that has a matching name.

```
userData.find(o => o.name === valueToSearch);
```

If such an object was found, you can extract its property names through [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), filter out unwanted properties and extract relevant values as follows.

```
Object.keys(row)
  .filter(k => k !== 'id' && k !== 'name')
  .map(k => row[k])
  .join(', ');
```

Please have a look at below runnable code snipeet.

```js
const userData = [{
    id: 0,
    name: 'Bob', //I need to search for this attribute and return all others
    full_name: 'Robert Shawn',
    number: 123456789,
    team: 'IT',
    profile: 'ALL',
    file: 5672,
    email: 'robsh@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Jean',
    full_name: 'Mary Jean',
    number: 987654321,
    team: 'HR',
    profile: 'Sales',
    file: 1285,
    email: 'mjean@gmail.com'
  }
];
const valueToSearch = 'Bob';

const row = userData.find(o => o.name === valueToSearch);
if (row) {
  const values = Object.keys(row)
  .filter(k => k !== 'id' && k !== 'name')
  .map(k => row[k])
  .join(', ');
  console.log('found: ' + values)
} else {
  console.log('not found');
}
```